# F#: Try-with block for checking whether a regex pattern is valid

Tags: regex, f#

I am new to programming and F# is my first .NET language.

As a beginner's project, I would like to create a regex query tool that would determine whether a regex pattern entered by the user is valid. I have been advised that I can do so with a try-with block to see whether the regex pattern compiles, but as I am still extremely unfamiliar with programming in general, I have trouble using [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ek5zak6(v=vs.110).aspx), as I have no idea what to specify as the second parameter.

1. Am I looking at the correct method?
2. Can a more experienced programmer show me how to write a function that does the task I just described?

Thank you.

EDIT: Here is the code I have so far:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let askUserForFilePath() =
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the file (extension: .txt) from which to read all lines: ")
    let filePath = Console.ReadLine()
    filePath

let askUserForRegexPattern() =
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a regular expression: ")
    let regExp = Console.ReadLine()
    regExp

let getLinesFromFile (filePath: string) =
    let linesFromFile = File.ReadAllLines filePath
    linesFromFile 
    |> Array.reduce (+)
    |> string

let matchTextAgainstRegex (text: string) (regExp: string) =
    try 
        Regex.IsMatch(text, regExp)
    with

    if Regex.IsMatch(text, regExp) then
        let matchResults = Regex.Match(text, regExp)
        let stringsFound = []
        for eachGroup in matchResults.Groups do
            eachGroup.Value :: stringsFound |> ignore
        stringsFound 
        |> List.rev
        |> List.iter (fun eachString -> printfn "%s" eachString)
    else
```

My issue is not knowing how to complete the try-with block. The 'else' block is currently unfinished, but I will get to it later. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why doesn't it work? Can you provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Compilable Example](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: @MarkSeemann, I will edit my post with an example now.

Comment: Have you read the full answer on your last question (since it was edited)? It seems to address your problem

Comment: @MY_G "My issue is not knowing how to complete the try-with block." What do you want your code to do in the case of an exception?

Comment: @JohnPalmer -- Thanks for notifying me. I'd missed that.

Comment: @MarkSeemann -- I'd like it to print a statement saying that something is syntactically wrong with the regex pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually have to test the regular expression against a string to see if it's valid. I mean if you want to check if the pattern is valid (not the string). You can simply instantiate a new `Regex` object and catch the exception.

```
type MatchResult =
| Ok
| Error of string

let matchTextAgainstRegex (regExp: string) (opt : RegexOptions) =
    try 
        let r = Regex(regExp, opt);
        Ok
    with
        | e -> Error(e.Message)
```

Note that I introduced a type `MatchResult` so you can match against it when it will be returned from `matchTextAgainstRegex` function. I've also changed the signature a little bit

So when you call it with an invalid pattern, here is the output :

> matchTextAgainstRegex @"^[" RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;;
>
> val it : MatchResult = Error "parsing "^[" - Unterminated [] set."

Comment: I would also suggest to change the name of the function to something like `isRegexValid` as you don't need a text anymore to check your regex.